# DynamoDB query performance with - a unique partition key vs a unique partition+sort key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Lets say I have a Dynamo DB table named 'student_course'. I want to store the course that each student is taking in a University. One student can take multiple courses at a time and one course can have many student at a time. So basically it is a multi-mapping.

My data access pattern has only one use case -

1. get a record of one student and one course at a time, i.e. is get data for each StudentId and CourseId combination. Its is guaranteed that for a student-id and course-id combination, there is only one record available.

To achieve this I can store the data in these 2 ways -

1. Partition-key = {student-id}, sort-key = {course-id}
2. Partition-key = "studentId:{student-id}_courseId:{course-id}", sort-key does not exist

My Question is - Which query would perform better, if there is any difference, that is? Which one should I choose over the other and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of designing for `DDB` Performance, the `Get API` is key to milli-seconds data retrieval capability of DDB, therefore it is logical to design your data around this API

**Table with Partition Key + Sort Key**

```
Partition Key | Sort Key    
--------------+-------------
Course1       | Student1
Course1       | Student2
```

Advantage:

1. Able to use the `Get API` to get a Single record by the `Partition Key` and the `Sort Key` e.g. Get single record where Partition Key = "Course1" and Sort Key = "Student1"
2. Able to use the `Get API` to get a List of records by only the `Partition Key` e.g. Get all records where Partition Key = "Course1"

Disadvantage:

1. If you know only the `Sort Key` (i.e. Student) and not the `Partition Key` (i.e. Course), you won't be able to use the `Get API` to retrieve the record only by the `Sort Key`

*Note: In general, the efficiency (such that queries do not hit the `ReadThroughput` exception "Roof" easily) of DDB `Get API` queries is quite coupled with the uniqueness and distribution of the `Partition Key`. The more the partition keys you have and spreaded out, the better the performance*

**Table with Partition Key only**

```
Partition Key Only   
--------------------
Course1#Student1
Course1#Student2
```

Advantage:

1. Able to use the `Get API` to get a Single record by the `Partition Key` e.g. Get single record where Partition Key = "Course1#Student1"

Disadvantage:

1. Will not be able to use the `Get API` to get a List of records using only a subset of the `Partition key` e.g. Get a List of records where Partition Key = "Course1"

**About GSIs**

*Note: It is a common scenario to add **Global Secondary Index** on Tables to support `Get API` calls using an alternate key, like *Get a List of records where `GSI Partition Key` = Course Name**

```
Partition Key Only   | Non Key Attribute (Course) For GSI
---------------------+---------------------------
Course1#Student1     | Course1
Course1#Student2     | Course1
```

You can have up to 20 `GSI` Indexes (soft limit), with the option to remove this limit through a Support request

```
Partition Key Only   | Non Key Attribute (Course) For GSI | Lecturer (For GSI 2)
---------------------+------------------------------------+---------------------
Course1#Student1     | Course1                            | Lecturer1
Course1#Student2     | Course1                            | Lecturer1
```

**Conclusion**

I would design a Table to have as many **Unique** values for the `Partition Keys` as possible if the Performance is key i.e. Partition Key = Course1#Student1 VS Partition Key = Course1, Sort Key = Student1

Add `GSIs` to Tables *on-demand* if you need to query by an alternate key

(Historically `GSIs` were limited to 5 per Table, and had to be specified during Table creation, but these limitations are since lifted)